# How to get an access from external ip to internal ip using NGINX on GCP?

Tags: networking, nginx, reverse-proxy, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I can't connect to an application through an External IP.

I started a [gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/) code review application on a GCP's Compute Engine instance (with CentOS 7).

It works on a console, by `curl http://localhost:8080` but I can't connect to it through external IP.

I've also tried to create a NGINX server. After installing NGINX, the starter page were shown on external ip, but the reverse proxy configuration does not show gerrit register page.

```
server {
listen 80;

access_log /var/log/nginx/gerrit_access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/gerrit_error.log;

location / {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}

gerrit.config
[httpd]
listenUrl = proxy-http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

Finally, I want to see gerrit register page when using an external ip.

Answer (score 1):

That Nginx reverse proxy configuration seems correct, but I would definitively recommend using HTTPS if you're going to expose this to the outside world.

A few things you need to keep in mind:

- Make sure gerrit is running and listening on port 8080. You can do that with `netstat -atun | grep 8080`.
- I would also check out [this document](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/v2.7-rc0/Documentation/config-reverseproxy.txt) to make sure you gerrit configuration is correct.
- If you didn't allow HTTP traffic when creating the VM instance, you will need to tag the instance with the default "http-server" firewall tag.
- Make sure firewalld isn't blocking incoming incoming traffic.

If none of that solves it I would start by looking at nginx logs and examine the output on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the app is listening on 0.0.0.0 and make sure the firewall for this port is enabled.